# How do I instruct a custom JSON.NET JsonConverter to recognize that a particular property has already been serialized upstream?

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a touch of a predicament.  I have a collection of `System.Security.Claims.Claim` and the constructor of Claim requires the `value` parameter to contain a string.  The value of a particular claim needs to be a `JArray` that contains `JObject` and I can easily enough walk my structure during creation and build what I need to build, but I can't figure out how to instruct the Serializer to keep its hands off of *that* particular Claim.

```
string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
JObject json = JObject.Parse(content);
List<JObject> foos = new List<JObject>();
var foosComingFromSomewhereElseWithADifferentStructure = json["foos"];
bool first = true;
foreach (var _foo in foosComingFromSomewhereElseWithADifferentStructure.Children<JObject>())
{
   JObject foo = new JObject();
   string bar = (string)_foo["quux"].Value<JToken>();
   string baz = (string)_foo["inga"].Value<JToken>();
   foo.Add("Baz", baz);
   foo.Add("Bar", bar);
   foos.Add(foo);
}

claims.Add(new Claim("FooBar", (string)JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foos)));
```

After the block of code above runs, I continue processing and I then need to pass the whole enchilada through a Json Serializer ( my serialization essentially needs to be performed in multiple passes)

So if I were to *now* need to pass the list of claims through yet another JSON.NET `JsonConverter`, how would I best declare to the Serializer to keep its hands off of FooBar because its value has already been prepared as JSON?

Right now, my serializer is spitting out:

```
{
   "FooBar": "[{\"Baz"\":\"inga\",\"Bar\":\"quux\"}]
}
```

when I need it to be spitting out

```
{
   "FooBar": [{"Baz":"inga","Bar":"quux"}]
}
```

Comment: If you only care about serialization, you could use [`JsonWriter.WriteRaw()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonWriter_WriteRaw.htm) in your `JsonConverter`.  It lets you write anything.  But to read, the JSON must be valid; you can load to a `JToken` and return back its `ToString()`.  Beyond that, can you show an example converter as an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 4):

To do this kind of thing, you'd need to make a custom `JsonConverter`.  The converter could detect whether the claim value is JSON or not, and if so, use a `JRaw` to insert the already prepared value into the rest of the JSON body without being escaped or changed.  On the flip side, if the converter received an object instead of a string for the claim value (which it would if the value was unescaped JSON), then it would have to re-serialize that object to JSON before putting into the claim object.

Something like this might work:

```
class ClaimConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(System.Security.Claims.Claim));
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var claim = (System.Security.Claims.Claim)value;
        JObject jo = new JObject();
        jo.Add("Type", claim.Type);
        jo.Add("Value", IsJson(claim.Value) ? new JRaw(claim.Value) : new JValue(claim.Value));
        jo.Add("ValueType", claim.ValueType);
        jo.Add("Issuer", claim.Issuer);
        jo.Add("OriginalIssuer", claim.OriginalIssuer);
        jo.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
        string type = (string)jo["Type"];
        JToken token = jo["Value"];
        string value = token.Type == JTokenType.String ? (string)token : token.ToString(Formatting.None);
        string valueType = (string)jo["ValueType"];
        string issuer = (string)jo["Issuer"];
        string originalIssuer = (string)jo["OriginalIssuer"];
        return new Claim(type, value, valueType, issuer, originalIssuer);
    }

    private bool IsJson(string val)
    {
        return (val != null &&
                (val.StartsWith("[") && val.EndsWith("]")) ||
                (val.StartsWith("{") && val.EndsWith("}")));
    }
}
```

Demo:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var someJson = @"
        [
            { ""quux"": ""abc"", ""inga"": ""def"" },
            { ""quux"": ""pqr"", ""inga"": ""stu"" }
        ]";

        JArray foosComingFromSomewhereElse = JArray.Parse(someJson);

        List<JObject> foos = new List<JObject>();
        foreach (var _foo in foosComingFromSomewhereElse.Children<JObject>())
        {
            JObject foo = new JObject();
            string bar = (string)_foo["quux"].Value<JToken>();
            string baz = (string)_foo["inga"].Value<JToken>();
            foo.Add("Baz", baz);
            foo.Add("Bar", bar);
            foos.Add(foo);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("--- Original FooBar JSON ---");
        string foobarJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foos);
        Console.WriteLine(foobarJson);
        Console.WriteLine();

        List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>();
        claims.Add(new Claim("FooBar", foobarJson));

        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new ClaimConverter() },
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented
        };

        Console.WriteLine("--- Serialized list of claims ---");
        string claimsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(claims, settings);
        Console.WriteLine(claimsJson);
        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.WriteLine("--- Deserialized claim values ---");
        claims = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Claim>>(claimsJson, settings);
        foreach(Claim claim in claims)
            Console.WriteLine(claim.Value);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
--- Original FooBar JSON ---
[{"Baz":"def","Bar":"abc"},{"Baz":"stu","Bar":"pqr"}]

--- Serialized list of claims ---
[
  {
    "Type": "FooBar",
    "Value": [{"Baz":"def","Bar":"abc"},{"Baz":"stu","Bar":"pqr"}],
    "ValueType": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string",
    "Issuer": "LOCAL AUTHORITY",
    "OriginalIssuer": "LOCAL AUTHORITY"
  }
]

--- Deserialized claim values ---
[{"Baz":"def","Bar":"abc"},{"Baz":"stu","Bar":"pqr"}]
```

Comment: ...I will be tinkering with this first thing in the morning and I will report back if it is a success. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: So, if I create a Custom Converter `noopConverter` that contains `public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) {return false;}` and I pass this as the only Converter to `JsonSerializeObject(jsonObject, new List<JsonConverter>{ new noopConverter()})` what is supposed to happen when I call `SerializeObject`? Is this supposed to cause the Serializer to perform its **default** serialization or **no** serialization?

Comment: The serializer calls `CanConvert` to ask a converter if it can handle a particular object type.  If the converter returns false then the serializer asks the next converter (if any).  If there are no converters that handle that type, the serializer uses its default methods to handle it.

Comment: That's the behavior I was expecting to hear(and what I thought as well)...I'll have to tinker in the morning. I'm in a scenario where passing a `noopConverter` as the only converter into the converter list for `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` produces different results than using the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(object value)` overload.

Comment: If you run into trouble, post it as a new question.  That way more people will see it and be able to give a proper answer.  You can add a link back to this question if you need to provide context.